# markerwithlabel didnt display on google map on meteorjs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

markerwithlabel didnt display on google map on meteorjs. I am using dburles:google-maps and markerwithlabel v1.1.9. I cant seem to be able to integrate with dburles:google-maps and i placed markerwithlabel.js in public folder

I have this error

> Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.MarkerWithLabel is not a function

GoogleMap.jsx

```
Map = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    options: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },

  componentDidMount() {

    GoogleMaps.create({
      name: this.props.name,
      element: React.findDOMNode(this),
      options: this.props.options
    })

    GoogleMaps.ready(this.props.name, function(map) {
      var marker = new google.maps.MarkerWithLabel({ <-----------ERROR
        position: map.options.center,
        map: map.instance,
        zoom: 8
      })
    })
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (GoogleMaps.maps[this.props.name]) {
      google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(GoogleMaps.maps[this.props.name].instance);
      delete GoogleMaps.maps[this.props.name];
    } 
  },

  render() {
    return <div className="map-container"></div>;
  }
})
```

Home.jsx

```
Home = React.createClass({

  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  componentDidMount() {
    GoogleMaps.load({key: "AIzaSyAIoRRWbFOLmP4iLXrRmgDmNw0STlKMXqU"})
  },

  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      loaded: GoogleMaps.loaded(),
      mapOptions: GoogleMaps.loaded() && this._mapOptions()
    }
  },

  _mapOptions() {
    return {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.3, 103.8),
      zoom: 8
    }
  },

  render() {
    if (!this.data.loaded) {
        return <div>Loading map...</div>
    }

    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.src = '/markerwithlabel.js'
    document.body.appendChild(script)

    return <Map name="mymap" options={this.data.mapOptions}/>
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i get it. its a little dumb just use MarkerWithLabel rather than google.map.MarkerWithLabel because the api doesnt comes from google maps api

```
GoogleMaps.ready(this.props.name, function(map) {
      var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: map.options.center,
        map: map.instance,
        zoom: 8,
        labelContent: "$425K",
      })
    })
```